# How to run `drush make` on the existing Drupal installation?

Tags: drush

Whenever I try to run this command for a second time I get an error.

```
drush -v make /home/testdev/xipdrupalbasic.make /home/testdev/drupal
```

> ```
> Loading release_info engine.                                            [notice]
> Base path /home/testdev/drupal already exists                           [error]
> Command dispatch complete
> ```

I get why it gives me this error, but I would like a way of giving a force or overwrite command with it so it still runs. I get the error because it tries to make a directory that already exist.

I already tried  the adding `-r` to it but it will then just install it in the directory you execute the command.

When i just do:

```
drush -v make /home/testdev/xipdrupalbasic.make
```

in the directory where I want it, it will work without a problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can run `drush make` again on the existing Drupal installation, but you've to specify `--no-core` parameter.

> `drush make --no-core`                      Build an installation profile within an existing Drupal site

Comment: I came here trying to figure out what was broken with the `--overwrite` option, settled for `--no-core` (but still confused)